# How to animate tableview cells from bottom to top

Tags: uitableview, swift4

I have a tableview which grows and shrink on user click. When user lands to the screen the height of tableview is same as cell(single cell). On click of that cell multiple cells get populated and tableview height would be same as no. Of cells. I want have animation from last cell to first cell, but what I am getting is animation from first cell to last cell, my tableview is at bottom of the screen(which grows in upper direction)

This is my code inside will display method

```
cell.alpha = 0 
UIView.animate(with 
duration:0.4,
delay:0.05*Double 
( 
indexPath.row),animation: {
cell.alpha = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you want a tableView to scroll from bottom to top.

```
// scroll from bottom to top with delay
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
    tableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
}
```